# Hide Product Name in Woocommerce Invoice Mail

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to hide the product names (but not the product attributes) in the Completed Order mail sent to customers.
Like this:

[image]

I haven't found any solution for this yet. Trying to play around with the functions.php.

Thank you a lot!